# C# Retrieving data and storing it in a list

Tags: c#, forms, list, inheritance

I've been trying to learn some C# by creating a basic banking application that allows a user to add a current or savings account. If it's a current account then it multiplies the starting balance by 0.2 and if its a savings, then it multiples by 0.6. When they add an account, the application should save it to a list and finally display all the account names. So far I have a the form which allows the user to add an account called AddAccount.cs. I then have an Account.cs which should set the account and then a AccountList.cs which adds it to a list.

**What I need help with:**

1. How do I pass the new account details and set them in the Account.cs?
2. How then to add the account to the list and display the name of the Account?

**Account.cs:**

```
abstract class Account
    {
        public string accName, accId, accType;
        public double balance;

        public void setValues(string name, string id, double bal, string type)
        {
            this.accName = name;
            this.accId = id;
            this.balance = bal;
            this.accType = type;
        }
    }

    class CurrentAccount : Account
    {
        public double interst()
        {
            return balance * 0.2;
        }
    }

    class SavingsAccount : Account
    {
        public double interst()
        {
            return balance * 0.6;
        }
    }
```

**AddAccount.cs:**

```
private void btn_AddAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name, id, type;
            double balance;

            name = input_AccountName.Text;
            id = input_AccountNo.Text;
            balance = Convert.ToDouble(input_StartBalance.Text);

            if (radio_CurrentAccount.Checked)
            {
                type = "C";
            }
            else
            {
                type = "S";
            }

            //closes the form when clicked
            this.Close();
        }
```

**AccountList.cs:**

```
class AccountList
    {
        private List<Account> accountlst;
        public List<Account> AccountLst
        {
            get { return accountlst; }
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if I'm completely wrong. Even the slightest bit of help would be appreciated.

Comment: In AddAccount.cs you extract the input and set local variables. When the code exits from the add click you loose everything, You need a class level variable of type Account and set its properties, then you add this Account to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well assuming that if type is "C" then you create an object of type current account and if type is "S" then you create a savings account it would look something like this (by the way im going to do this in pseudo-code):

```
if (type is C) 
   Create new CurrentAccount object 
   call setValues(name, id, bal, type) //these are the local variable you created in AddAccount.cs
   getAccountlst().add(CurrentAccount object you created) //adds to list
else 
   Create new SavingsAccount object 
   call setValues(name, id, bal, type) 
   getAccountlst().add(SavingsAccount object you created) //adds to list
```

By the way 2 problems, since you never initialized the accountlst object inside AccountList.cs by calling the new operator, it is set to null, so when you call getAccountlst() it will return a null object and if you try to add to it you will get a null pointer exception! And the pther problem, Since your AccountList.cs has to be initialized with new  operator, you can lose your information inside your list, to fix this you can do something like:

```
static class AccountList {

   List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>(); 

   public List<Account> Accountlst { 

       get {
           return accountList; 
       }
   }
}
```

Now to add to your list all you have to do is `AccountList.Accountlst.add(Account object here);`

Comment: Thank you this is perfect! :)